# Understanding event inside waypoints and printing it to the console

Tags: javascript

I was going through the source of waypoints.js and came across the following function ::

```
NoFrameworkAdapter = function(event, handler) {
  var eventParts = event.split('.')
  var eventType = eventParts[0]
  var namespace = eventParts[1] || '__default'
  var nsHandlers = this.handlers[namespace] = this.handlers[namespace] || {}
  var nsTypeList = nsHandlers[eventType] = nsHandlers[eventType] || []
  nsTypeList.push(handler)
  this.element.addEventListener(eventType, handler)
}
```

To understand this function, I wanted to console.log events so I wrote the below code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('a');
handler = function(){console.log('test')};
elem.addEventListener(event , handler); // error is throw here .
```

Since I am passing `event` instead of event type to the add event listener, an error is thrown, but all I really want  to do is to print the event to the console, so I can see the contents of it. 
How can I do that?  I know that I am missing something but I cannot find it.

The function concerned can be seen **[HERE](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/lib/noframework.waypoints.js#L657)** ,

Comment: Have you googled `addEventListener`?

Comment: Next time, please try to write terser. We want to help you but do not need to read a novel of your life to do so ;)